# python pandas adding group by calculations back into data frame

Tags: python, pandas

IM practicing with sample data to learn pandas.  I've started with some stock data since its easy to work with.

I have some data like this:

| symbol | date_time | close | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XOM | 2021-04-13 13:00:00 | 56.5 | 10000 |
| XOM | 2021-04-13 13:01:00 | 57.5 | 10000 |
| XOM | 2021-04-13 13:02:00 | 56.25 | 10000 |
| XOM | 2021-04-13 13:03:00 | 58.5 | 10000 |

I wanted to calculate a simple moving average, and then add it as a new column to existing dataframe.

This works... But I am wondering if there is a more pythonic/pandas way of doing this?

```
sma = quote_data.groupby("symbol")["close"].rolling(window=5, center=False).mean()
sma_list = sma.tolist()
quote_data['sma'] = sma_list
```

I tried to do

```
quote_data['sma'] = quote_data.groupby("sym")["close"].rolling(window=5, center=False).mean()
```

but that results in TypeError: Expected tuple, got str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chain [`droplevel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) method:

```
quote_data['sma']=quote_data.groupby("symbol")["close"].rolling(window=5, center=False).mean().droplevel(0)
```

Now if you print `quote_data` you will get your desired output:

```
   symbol   date_time               close   volume  sma
0   XOM     2021-04-13 13:00:00     56.50   10000   NaN
1   XOM     2021-04-13 13:01:00     57.50   10000   NaN
2   XOM     2021-04-13 13:02:00     56.25   10000   NaN
3   XOM     2021-04-13 13:03:00     58.50   10000   NaN
```

**Explaination:**

```
quote_data['sma']=quote_data.groupby("symbol")["close"].rolling(window=5, center=False).mean()
```

The above code returning you a Series that has multi index

```
symbol   
XOM     0   NaN
        1   NaN
        2   NaN
        3   NaN
```

And you can cross verify it by using `.index` attribute:

```
quote_data.groupby("symbol")["close"].rolling(window=5, center=False).mean().index

#output of above code

MultiIndex([('XOM', 0),
            ('XOM', 1),
            ('XOM', 2),
            ('XOM', 3)],
           names=['symbol', None])
```

So we chained `droplevel()` method and pass `0` as an parameter so that It drops the 0th level of multiIndex.So that the Series now has only a single index.

so Now your series look like

```
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
```

Now If we check the index of series:

```
quote_data.groupby("symbol")["close"].rolling(window=5, center=False).mean().droplevel(0).index

#output of above code

Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```

And Finally we assigned It to your dataframe by using this code:

```
quote_data['sma']=quote_data.groupby("symbol")["close"].rolling(window=5, center=False).mean().droplevel(0)
```